# Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference, But it is NOT a null reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

using: MVC 4, ASP.NET Razor

I'm getting an error that looks like it shouldn't be possible. It tells me that i'm using a null-reference, States, but clearly it is being set.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Dictionary<int, string> states = new Dictionary<int, string>()
    {
        { -1, "a"},
        { 0, "b"},
        { 1, "c"},
        { 2, "d"},
    };

    //assigning states
    ViewBag.States = states;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> de in ViewBag.States)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(de.Key);
    }
    return View();
}
```

The View:

```
<div class="search-input">
    <select>
        @foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> de in ViewBag.States)
        {
            <option value="@de.Key">@de.Value</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

The error:

```
Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
Line 54: @foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> de in ViewBag.States)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's correctly going through your method first?

Comment: Put breakpoints in your `Index()` method and the view, and see if that helps you see what's wrong.

Comment: Found my own answer, everything was right, inside my view i had a typo on a completely unrelated object, i had a ViewBag.TypoObject <-- this caused everything to get messed up

Answer (score 117):

Found solution: I had typo in my view, ViewBag.Typo <-- this caused the error, but the debugger placed the exception at a irrelevant place.

Comment: Just had the same issue where the debugger was placing the exception at the wrong point in the view. I had a null reference further down.

Comment: Very annoying trait. I mean really, debugger, if you don't know what or where the problem is it actually makes things _harder_ when you pretend you do.

Comment: Arggggg ! Just spent an hour on this ! Had a partial view that was being used a few diff places ... Model was generated the EXACT same but was erroring when referrenced from one actionresult and not the other. Ended up being a ViewBag issue as well. It was getting set in one action and not in the other. FRUSTRATING!!!

Comment: This saved me some time as well.  Had a similar problem where I was accessing a ViewBag property that no longer existed but the error 'Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference' made it look like it was happening way up on an unrelated part of the code.

Comment: wait - what was the typo?

Comment: Deary me. Just succumbed to this where it was listing an exception as being in a script block but the error was actually in a div half way down the page. V.Helpful.. :(

Comment: There was a null property in model i was trying to show. But error was shown somewhere else

Comment: Since I've been here a couple times. My typo is capitalizing the model assignment line.

Comment: As well as ViewBag.TypoObject this can also be caused by Model.TypoObject when you are using 

    @model dynamic

Answer (score 20):

This error happens when you have a ViewBag **Non-Existent** in your razor code calling a method.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Accept(int id)
{
    return View();
}
```

**razor:**

```
<div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ToId, "To", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.Flag(Model.from)
     </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-md-10">
          <input value="@ViewBag.MaximounAmount.ToString()" />@* HERE is the error *@ 
     </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, the .net aren't able to show the error in the correct line.

Normally this causes a lot of wasted time.

Answer (score 18):

This exception is also thrown when a non-existent property is being updated dynamically, using reflection.

If one is using reflection to dynamically update property values, it's worth checking to make sure the passed `PropertyName` is identical to the actual property.

In my case, I was attempting to update `Employee.firstName`, but the property was actually `Employee.FirstName`.

Worth keeping in mind. :)

Answer (score 5):

My solution to this error was that a copy and paste from another project that had a reference to `@Model.Id`. This particular page didn't **have** a model but the error line was so far off from the actual error I about never found it!

Answer (score 2):

Not related to Razor, you'll see that exception in runtime trying access not existed property inside the dynamic value:

```
dynamic myValue;
if(myValue.notExistedProperty == "some-value") { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must define states not equal to null..

```
@if (ViewBag.States!= null)
{
    @foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> de in ViewBag.States)
    {
        value="@de.Key">@de.Value 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Set

```
 Dictionary<int, string> states = new Dictionary<int, string>()
```

as a property outside the function and inside the function insert the entries, it should work.

Comment: Uh, what? Properties of the controller aren't accessible from the view, that's why there's a ViewBag and/or ViewModel...

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with using a collection initializer.  This will NOT solve the problem.