# Getting error of "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type...."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm making a website using asp.net mvc 4 & EF6 where admins can add new client information. So far everything is working fine but whenever I try to save the data by pressing `Add` button I get this error,

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyMvc.Models.UserInfo', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyMvc.Models.BrManagement'

Here are my codes,

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ClientManager(BrManagement ClTable)
    {
        if (Session["AdminNAME"] != null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var AddClient = ClTable.AddUserInfo;
                abdb.UserInfoes.Add(AddClient);
                abdb.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("ClientManager", new { ClPanelId = "AllCl" });
            }
            return View(ClTable.AddUserInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("AdminLogin");
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class BrManagement
{
    public Branch Branches { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Branch> BrCollection { get; set; }
    public UserInfo AddUserInfo { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<UserInfo> UserCollection { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ClientManager", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <strong>Client USER ID</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.UserId)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.UserId)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <strong>Client Password</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.Password)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.Password)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <strong>Full Name</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.Name, new { size = 30 })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.Name)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <strong>Address</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.AddressLine1, new { size = 30 })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.AddressLine1)
                </div>
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.CreatedDate, new { @Value = System.DateTime.Now })
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.IsActive, new { @Value = "N" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.IsApproved, new { @Value = "N" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.IsinfoMatched, new { @Value = "N" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.IsReportView, new { @Value = "N" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.IsVarified, new { @Value = "N" })
                <br />
                <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Add" /></p>
            }
```

I've used the same code for `Branches` & `BrCollection` model, both of them are working fine. `UserCollection` model is also working fine. Why is this happening for `AddUserInfo` model? I've searched a lot but couldn't find any solution similar to mine. Need this help really bad. Your help will be appreciated! Tnx.

**UPDATE**
**View(FULL)**

```
@model ABCoLtd.Models.BrManagement

@{
ViewBag.Title = "ClientManager";
string active = ViewBag.ClActive.ToString();
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ALayout.cshtml";
}
<link href="~/Content/DataTables-1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<body>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var tabpane = '@active';
        $("#" + tabpane).addClass("active");
        $('#BrTable').DataTable({
            "aoColumns": [
            { "bSortable": true },
            { "bSortable": true },
            { "bSortable": true },
            { "bSortable": true }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
<br /><br /><br /><br />
<div class="container well" style="min-width: 100%; padding-right: 5px;">
    <h3>Client Manager</h3><hr style="border-top: 2px solid #096596;" />
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#AllCl" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">All Clients</a>   </li>
        <li><a href="#AddCl" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Add Clients</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="AllCl" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">
            <h4>Manage Clients</h4><hr style="border-top: 2px solid #096596;" />
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="BrTable" class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr><th>BOID</th><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach(var item in Model.UserCollection)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone1)</td></tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="AddCl" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">
            <h4>Add Client</h4><hr style="border-top: 2px solid #096596;" />
            @using (Html.BeginForm("ClientManager", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <strong>Client BO Account No.</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.BOAccountNo, new { size = 30 })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.BOAccountNo)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <strong>Client USER ID</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.UserId)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.UserId)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <strong>Client Password</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.Password)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.Password)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <strong>Full Name</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.Name, new { size = 30 })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.Name)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <strong>Address</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.AddressLine1, new { size = 30 })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.AddressLine1)
                </div>
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.CreatedDate, new { @Value = System.DateTime.Now })
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.IsActive, new { @Value = "N" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.IsApproved, new { @Value = "N" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.IsinfoMatched, new { @Value = "N" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.IsReportView, new { @Value = "N" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.IsVarified, new { @Value = "N" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.UserType, new { @Value = "C" })
                <br />
                <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Add" /></p>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your returning `return View(ClTable.AddUserInfo);` The property `AddUserInfo` is type of `UserInfo`, not `BrManagement` - change it to `return View(ClTable);`

Comment: Do you have an `@model MyMvc.Models.BrManagement` statement in your view?

Comment: @devqon, yes. I've that.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Now I get this error, `Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference` on the begining of my view, `Line 5:      string active = ViewBag.ClActive.ToString();`

Comment: Your not setting the value of `ViewBag.ClActive` when you return the view, so its null, hence the error. But you have numerous other errors anyway, such as ` @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.AddUserInfo.IsActive, new { @Value = "N" })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, tnx. So how can I fix that?

Comment: Your need to set `ViewBag.ClActive = someValue;` before you return the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I've added these codes in my controller, `string ClPanelId = "AllCl"; ViewBag.ClActive = ClPanelId; return RedirectToAction("ClientManager", new { ClPanelId = "AllCl" });`. Still same error showing.

Comment: No, I mean when you return the view (because `ModelState` is invalid - and probably always will be based on the code in your view), not when you redirect.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, please check my updated post. I've updated the whole view codes. Tell me if there is something wrong there?

Comment: What is the type of property `AddUserInfo.IsActive` (the name suggest its bool)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, in MSSQL db its varchar(1)

Answer (score 0):

Your view expect `BrManagement`

```
@model MyMvc.Models.BrManagement
```

But you returned `ClTable.AddUserInfo` which is type of `UserInfo`, that is why you got that error.

To fix this, change `return View(ClTable.AddUserInfo);` to `return View(ClTable);` in your controller.

Comment: Now I get this error, `Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference` on the begining of my view, `Line 5: string active = ViewBag.ClActive.ToString();`

Comment: check if there's a typo in your ViewBag. Make sure ViewBag.ClActive exist.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457804/cannot-perform-runtime-binding-on-a-null-reference-but-it-is-not-a-null-referen

Comment: I don't understand, I found no typo. Would it be ok if I give the whole `View` code so you can have a better look?

Comment: Sure, I'm pretty sure ViewBag.ClActive doesn't exist and you're trying to get the value from it like Stephen said.