# Call methods inside webapi synchronously

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have POST method which is saving data into database.

```
[POST]
public void SaveData()
{
  try
  {
    BusinessLayer businessLayerObject = new BusinessLayer();
    businessLayerObject.SaveDataIntoDB();
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {}
}
```

BusinessLayer.cs :-

```
public void SaveDataIntoDB()
{
  try
  {
    using (var context = new EntityContext())
   {
    using (DbContextTransaction transaction=context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
 .... ......
    }
   }
  }
catch(Exception ex)
  {}
}
```

When multiple requests are there at a same time for SaveData method, I want SaveDataIntoDB() method to get called synchronously.
When Processing of one SaveDataIntoDB() method gets completed , it should call other.
What can be done to do so?

Currently it is not doing so.

Comment: Are you wanting some kind of queue?

Comment: not exactly queue , but my need is , it should call SaveDataIntoDB method one by one when multiple requests.

Comment: And do you want them processed in a First in, First out manner? Or just when when is done, grab any from the collection of jobs waiting to be processed?

Comment: You can create a static object and use `lock` on it. Should work

Comment: @Dave yes.. FIFO

Comment: you need to explain clearer what your problem is. What is the behaviour you're seeing and what is the behaviour you need. The way the code is now, they will execute in whatever order they're coming in and some will execute at the same time even. SQL has a pool of connections available. So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Why is the order of SQL commands that important?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference, But it is NOT a null reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457804/cannot-perform-runtime-binding-on-a-null-reference-but-it-is-not-a-null-referen)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a queue (FIFO). How to implement that depends highly on how your deployment is.

If you're using a single instance deployment, you can create a class that wraps a `Queue<T>`. It should be implemented as a singleton and in a async fashion sends the queued messages to the database.

If you're using a scale out approach, you will need something like RabbitMQ, MSMQ or other message queue...